# Check if int is in list of ints in Java (with some constraints)

Tags: java

I'm looking for a simple and elegant one line way to check if the `int` result of an expression is contained in a list of integers.

Example: Check if `foo(…)` produces either 1, 2 or 7.

Constraints:

- Do not use external libraries, only the JRE.
- Java 8 can be assumed.
- Solution does not involve (auto)boxing. I personally don't like boxing :-P
- `foo(…)` should only be evaluated once.
- No additional method should be required.
- No mutable variables should be required.
- One or two `final` variables may be used, including lambdas. But `foo(…)` (and its result) and the list of `int`s should not be part of this variables.
- The list of integers to check against is known at compile time and may be up to 5 numbers.

To illustrate: `java.util.Arrays.asList(1, 2, 7).contains(foo(…))` meets all criteria except it requires boxing.

---

Note: I'm only interested what possible solutions could look like. In practice I would probably use my illustration example, [`ArrayUtils.contains(…)` from Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#contains(int[],%20int)) or [`Ints.contains(…)` from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#contains(int[],%20int)).

I'll add three possible solutions later if they don't come up anyway. But I wonder if there are any more elegant solutions, as mine are not really that elegant and I'm a bit surprised Java does not seem to provide something like this out of the box.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because looks like a "do my homework" request disguised with the word "elegant".

Comment: as ugly as it gets: `Arrays.toString(ints).matches("[^0-9]" + value + "[^0-9]");`

Comment: @duffymo: Feel free to close it, but I promise it is definitely not a homework question, I'm just curious! ;-) Please also note the last paragraph in the question...

Comment: @njzk2: This was not what I was looking for, but still a creative solution, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about binary search?

```
Arrays.binarySearch(new int[] {1, 2, 7}, foo(...)) >= 0
```

Comment: Yes, this is one of the solutions I got, but it requires the numbers to be sorted (ok, that's not a problem with 3 or 5 numbers, but still). And it requires the `new int[] {…}` thing. It is still the solution i like most from the ones i got.

Comment: Note that `Arrays.asList` solution also requires creation of the new array (it's implicitly done by Java compiler when you use varargs).

Comment: Yes, I know, it's not about the array but about being verbose :-P

Comment: I accepted your answer as it is the most concise and most comprehensible for this job, even though it does not express the intend very well.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter out the results using a lambda instead, if you're guaranteed a `List`.  If you're not, you can wrap it inside of a `Arrays#asList` operation.

This will short-circuit on the first value that evaluates to `true`.

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(foo());
boolean exists = intList.stream().anyMatch(x -> x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 7);
```

There is going to be a level of boxing due to the way that the stream has to be created; if you *really* want to avoid it for whatever reason, you've got a couple of options.

- Create an `int[]`, then create an `IntStream` from it:

  ```
  boolean exists = Arrays.stream(new int[](foo()))
                         .anyMatch(x -> x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 7);
  ```
- Convert to an `IntStream` as an intermediate step (does involve boxing to a degree)

  ```
  boolean exists = intList.stream()
                          .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                          .anyMatch(x -> x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 7);
  ```

Comment: `foo(…)` only produces a single `int`. But your solution can be easily adapted. But it is relatively verbose to add another value to check against. Still, I did not think about it this way... :-)

Comment: Note that after your edit you are boxing the `int` which violates bullet point three…

Comment: @siegi:  I've updated my example to include an approach that doesn't involve boxing.  I will say that, from a professional standpoint, unless these operations are being done thousands of times per second, there's no reason to avoid boxing to such a degree.  Worry about other parts of the code base being performant as opposed to boxing.

Comment: Thank you! I know it does not really matter from a performance point of view. I mainly put the constraint in to exclude all the "obvious" solutions using `Collection`, `List`… and to make it more interesting ;-) And as I said, I don't like the (un)boxing very much. Mostly because of the potential NPE when (auto)unboxing (which once costed me some time of debugging but that would not matter in this case, of course).

Answer (score 1):

As promised in the question, here are my solutions:

Besides the one of [Tagir Valeev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31102383/1347968) using `Arrays.binarySearch(…)` I did some variations using lambdas:

- Building an [`IntPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntPredicate.html) by joining multiple predicates:

  ```
  final IntFunction<IntPredicate> intEquals = v1 -> v2 -> v1 == v2;
  intEquals.apply(1).or(intEquals.apply(2)).or(intEquals.apply(7)).test(foo(…));
  ```

  This makes adding a new number to the list very verbose.

  First building a `IntPredicate` avoids the need to encapsulate the result of `foo(…)` somehow to prevent evaluating it more than once.
- This one does the same as the previous solution, but adding a new number is less verbose (at the cost of a more complex lambda):

  ```
  final IntFunction<IntPredicate> intEquals = v1 -> v2 -> v1 == v2;
  final Function<Function<IntStream.Builder, IntStream.Builder>, IntPredicate> pred =
      c -> c.apply(IntStream.builder()).build().mapToObj(intEquals).reduce(IntPredicate::or).get();
  pred.apply(b -> b.add(1).add(2).add(7)).test(foo(…));
  ```
- Building a `IntPredicate` from an array:

  ```
  final Function<int[], IntPredicate> oneOf =
      ints -> testInt -> IntStream.of(ints).anyMatch(arrayInt -> testInt == arrayInt);
  oneOf.apply(new int[] { 1, 2, 7 }).test(foo(…));
  ```

  This is in principe similar to the answer provided by [Makoto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31102411/1347968) but the other way around (he put the single value in front of the stream).
- Using [`IntStream.of(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of-int...-) instead of writing `new int[] {…}`:

  ```
  final Function<IntStream, IntPredicate> oneOf =
      ints -> testInt -> ints.anyMatch(streamInt -> testInt == streamInt);
  oneOf.apply(IntStream.of(1, 2, 7)).test(foo(…));
  ```

  This could be even shortened using a static import of `IntStream.of`.
- With the use of [`BiPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html) the call can be made even shorter:

  ```
  final IntFunction<IntPredicate> intEquals = v1 -> v2 -> v1 == v2;
  final BiPredicate<IntStream, IntSupplier> oneOf =
      (list, value) -> list.anyMatch(intEquals.apply(value.getAsInt()));
  oneOf.test(of(1, 2, 7), () -> foo(…));
  ```

  Here a [`IntSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html) is used to avoid the recalculation of `foo(…)`.

---

So the bottom line for me is: Java does not provide a concise, ready to use function that meets the requirements. The `binarySearch` method works but requires a sorted list of integers and does not express the intend very well. The lambda variants are all a bit complex. So apparently I'll have to drop some of the constraints :-P

But it was an interesting challenge to look at, in my opinion…

Comment: It's interesting that you don't like quite cheap boxing operation, but it's ok for you to create several intermediate functions, predicates, etc. Btw, using boxing and streams: `IntStream.of(1,2,7).anyMatch(((Integer)foo())::equals)` (the `foo()` is evaluated only once).

Comment: @TagirValeev: Well, sometimes I'm a bit peculiar :-P Please also note that I do not recommend doing it this way nor do I think it is "good practice". I just wanted to explore some possible ways of doing it this way… As I already wrote in my question, in practice I would probably use the straight forward `Arrays.asList(…).contains(…)` method.